# How do I setup Dockerfile to run babel after install?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

When running `docker-compose up` I keep getting a babel error when trying to build out my nodejs code since it is written in ES6 with imports and not const.

> babel server.js -d dist && babel src -d dist/src
>
> babel:
>     server.js does not exist

My directory structure is:

- server.js
- src

  - all other js files

How should I be setting up my Dockerfile, as I'm apparently not understanding file locations when creating the containers.

So far I have tried moving my build location to a dist folder instead of build but that was just a file rename. I also tried changing my `COPY .` to `COPY server.js` and that failed as well.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/api
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/api
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/api
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4000
CMD npm run start
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel server.js -d dist && babel src -d dist/src",
    "dev-start": "babel-watch server.js",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/server.js"
  }
```

I expect the container to finish creating with the app built, and the actual result currently is a failed build and container failure.

Comment: Can you also show your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @shriek I will grab that as soon as I get home. I forgot to commit my changes to source control and I'm at the office right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have the wrong path in `COPY` command

Your path in `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/api`

Path in `COPY .      /usr/src/api`

Put the path as your path in `workdir` to a copy command like this `COPY . /usr/src/app/api`